# Is it possible to "create" (baseless) merge candidates within TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, branch

Here where I work we have a branch which is only used to check-in ongoing bugs and tasks. The small tasks are shelved and recovered in the next week, when they are checked-in.

We developed an *auto-merge system* where these small check-ins are all merged to all specific project Branches. Then, at the end of the project, it's reverse merged into the main branch, thus going automatically to another project branches.

But, suppose I have a branch with **Feature A**, and another with **Feature B**. I need a third, with both **Feature A + Feature B + Bug Fixes**. I don't want to reverse merge them as I don't want to mess up the main branch (yet)

I've created a branch from Feature A, and enabled my auto-merge from **"Feature A"** to **"Feature A+B"**. So every bug fix goes this way: **Main -> Feature A -> Feature A+B**. And every checkin within **Feature A goes to Feature A+B**.

> Now I want to do baseless merges from **"Feature B" to "Feature
> A+B"**.
>
> **Is there a way to enable merging between them (within TFS) ?**

I know it blows hierarchy up, and I know I can just perform x baseless merges through `tf.exe`, or three-way merge the files manually (or using any known tool).

But I'm not responsible for doing this, it's another developer who got used to the Team Explorer interface and all, so it would make his life easier.

Now, now, I know a probable answer/comment will be:

> "*You need to revisit your branch structure, as something is wrong!"*

If possible, put that with some tips, I'm currently trying to change that but I'm not sure what to do when we develop 2 separated projects that, all of a sudden, need to be put together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, once you have done a baseless merge between two branches using `tf merge /baseless`, TFS remembers this relation and from then on any user can perform a merge 'normally' between the two branches.

The catch is that the baseless merge probably will detect conflicts for every item, and you need to check in new versions of everything in order to create the relation between the branches for the items. So, using your branch structure and doing a baseless merge between **FeatureB** to **Feature A+B**, you must be very careful when solving the conflicts - if you simply select the target version, any **FeatureA** changes on the target branch will be overwritten with **FeatureB**!

I should add that I haven't done this all the way through; I had a similar scenario but bailed out when I realized that I needed to solve every conflict in detail. Our product is huge, so it wasn't worth the time and the risk for us.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know tfs remembered relationships after baseless merges ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your assessment of the situation is correct, you will need to use a baseless merge here to establish a relationship between Feature B and Feature A+B.  tbergstedt is correct that TFS will remember the merge relationship between the branches once it is established.  So, that means you will only need to perform one baseless merge in this scenario and then the normal merge UI in Team Explorer will pick up subsequent changes.

Now, as far as actually performing the baseless merge goes, it will need to be done from tf.exe using the /baseless option UNLESS you have a Team Explorer 2012 Beta client.  In Team Explorer 2012 we have added the ability to perform a baseless merge in the UI.  If you don't have one, I would suggest that you just perform the first baseless merge and then left your co-worker do the subsequent merges using the UI.

-Taylor, TFS Version Control Development Lead.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without actually DOING the merge?  I just want to establish the relationship.  Actually DOING the merge seems horribly risky because I'd have to merge every single file (thousands) and work has been done in both branches.  I just want to make it easier for developers to move work from one branch to the next. This limitation is frustrating.